# Create new columns from a column value in pandas based on an id

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this. What I would like to do is to create new columns where I will keep a unique id and several new columns.

In the other examples I can't find how to create new columns. There's only how to pivot using a column and values, but in my example I want to create new columns.

From here:

| id | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 3 | E |
| 3 | F |

To here:

| id | Label_1 | Label_1 | Label_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |  |
| 2 | C |  |  |
| 3 | D | E | F |

Comment: de-duplicate the id with `df.groupby('id').cumcount()` and use this as column to pivot (see #10 in duplicate)